# Retrieve Data from Dropdown list while form update

Tags: php, html, html-select

I am trying to write the update code for php where the update page will **show the PREVIOUSLY ENTERED DATA FROM DROP DOWN LIST selected by user** and the user can change that from other available options. 
Here is my piece of code

```
echo '<select id="locations" name="locations">'--------------**to show the previously entered data**
option value="USA">USA</option>-----------------**other available data to be selected**
<option value="India">India</option>
<option value="Dubai">Dubai</option>
</select>
```

Can someone tell where am I going wrong?

Comment: Your above PHP is invalid as it is missing the opening `<` from the first option. Please clarify the problem - it's not clear at present

Comment: No, actually its there in the original code. I just posted the problematic code here.

Comment: So explain what exactly about it is problematic then, please. Or perhaps go read [ask] and [mre] first of all.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is a users & countries table, and user can select their Country from drop down list, then do it this way:-

```
<select id="locations" name="locations">
  <?php foreach ($countries as $country): ?>
   <option value="<?= $country->code ?>" <?= ($country->code == $user->country) ? 'selected': '' ?>><?= $country->name ?></option>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

you're welcome to ask further questions.

Comment: Thank you sir for the response! Just wanna clarify, I have got just one table and the table name is 'data_info'. In that case what would be the code?
Sorry, I am just a beginner in php.

Comment: you're welcome, let me know where do store the selected value, and from where do you bring the countries.

Comment: The selected value is stored in the database table in the column name 'locations' and from where itself I want to echo the selected country in the display.php page.

Comment: Alright, the user is going to select the location, or who is going to select? let me know I will update the code

Comment: Actually, what I want is this: -> User will will enter a country from a drop down list in the insert.php page -> The inserted value will be displayed in the display.php page. There will be an update button beside it. -> The user can click the update button. It will redirect to update.php page where the previously entered drop down list value will be displayed, the one entered by user, along with the other available option.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to hazard a guess that what you are hoping to accomplish is similar to the following.

The `SELECT` menu would typcially be created using content from a database but it could be some other source, perhaps even static if there are few options. Given that there is a comment `other available data to be selected` I assumed there to be other locations and opted to show using an array.

Each time the `SELECT` menu is changed the javascript event listener will reload the page but will set the querystring ( and thus make available the GET variable ) to the selected location. The `SELECT` menu is generated by looping through the available locations array / recordset and for each item a comparison is made to the GET variable ( assigned to variable `$selection`. ) If the `$selection` variable matches the item in the array/recordset it is considered to be `selected`

A similar approach can be adopted to react to the form being POSTed - or you can use the `$_REQUEST` to cover both GET & POST

```
<?php
    $arr=array(
        'USA','England','Scotland','France','Italy','India','Dubai','Japan'
    );

    $selection=!empty( $_GET['locations'] ) ? filter_input( INPUT_GET,'locations',FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING) : false;
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>Maintain previously selected value in SELECT menu</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <select name='locations'>
             <option selected hidden disabled>Please select<?php
                foreach( $arr as $location ){
                    $selected=$selection && trim( $selection )==trim( $location ) ? ' selected' : '';
                    printf('
            <option value="%1$s"%2$s>%1$s', $location, $selected );
                }
            ?>
        </select>
        <script>
            document.querySelector('select[name="locations"]').addEventListener('change',function(e){
                location.search='locations='+this.value
            })
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed explanation but what I want is:

-> User will will enter a country from a drop down list in the insert.php page
-> The inserted value will be displayed in the display.php page. There will be an update button beside it.
-> The user can click the update button. It will redirect to update.php page where the previously entered drop down list value will be displayed, the one entered by user, along with the other available option.

Comment: What you want is??